# Drupal 7 / CiviCRM 4.2.8 - merge contacts

Tags: php, drupal-7, civicrm

Im new to CiviCRM and I am curious if there is a configuration that would allow for the Merge Contacts functionality to be done automatically?

I have read the documentation about the two rule types "Strict" and "Fuzzy" and it sounded like Strict was exactly what I wanted, since it will automatically run when a new contact is created via an online registration for an event.

I wanted this so that the new contact created from the online registration of an event would be merged with an existing contact that is part of a particular household.

Currently CiviCRM creates a new contact from the information on the online registration of the event but does not merge it with the contact with the same information that the Strict Rule is configured to mark contacts as duplicates.

If I go into the merge rules and run it manually it will find the two contacts and show them as duplicates, so I am wondering why it does not merge them when the new contact is created via the online registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for trying out CiviCRM!

I think the issue you're finding has been addressed in the lastest versions of CiviCRM, the problem was that contacts were only ever matched on email address on event registration, effectively ignoring the strict rule.

This is the JIRA issue

http://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-12117

As you can see its been fixed in CiviCRM 4.2.9

Thanks

Parvez Saleh (Veda Consulting Limited - UK Based CiviCRM Consultancy)